# Grid-Framework editing

Tags: grid, twig, bootstrap-4

I'm not familiar with "less", but I work with html and css. I'm trying to edit a page written by someone else and I need to change only one value, but I do not know where I can do it !! Can anybody help me!!?

This is the value I want to change!!
[grid-framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToNB8.png)

Below the grid-framework.less file code

And these are my options!!rsrsrs Oh man, I am so noooob on this!!
[grid-framework adress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV3zv.png)

```css
// Framework grid generation
//
// Used only by Bootstrap to generate the correct number of grid classes given
// any value of `@grid-columns`.

.make-grid-columns() {
  // Common styles for all sizes of grid columns, widths 1-12
  .col(@index) { // initial
    @item: ~".col-xs-@{index}, .col-sm-@{index}, .col-md-@{index}, .col-lg-@{index}";
    .col((@index + 1), @item);
  }
  .col(@index, @list) when (@index =< @grid-columns) { // general; "=<" isn't a typo
    @item: ~".col-xs-@{index}, .col-sm-@{index}, .col-md-@{index}, .col-lg-@{index}";
    .col((@index + 1), ~"@{list}, @{item}");
  }
  .col(@index, @list) when (@index > @grid-columns) { // terminal
    @{list} {
      position: relative;
      // Prevent columns from collapsing when empty
      min-height: 1px;
      // Inner gutter via padding
      padding-left:  ceil((@grid-gutter-width / 2));
      padding-right: floor((@grid-gutter-width / 2));
    }
  }
  .col(1); // kickstart it
}

.float-grid-columns(@class) {
  .col(@index) { // initial
    @item: ~".col-@{class}-@{index}";
    .col((@index + 1), @item);
  }
  .col(@index, @list) when (@index =< @grid-columns) { // general
    @item: ~".col-@{class}-@{index}";
    .col((@index + 1), ~"@{list}, @{item}");
  }
  .col(@index, @list) when (@index > @grid-columns) { // terminal
    @{list} {
      float: left;
    }
  }
  .col(1); // kickstart it
}

.calc-grid-column(@index, @class, @type) when (@type = width) and (@index > 0) {
  .col-@{class}-@{index} {
    width: percentage((@index / @grid-columns));
  }
}
.calc-grid-column(@index, @class, @type) when (@type = push) and (@index > 0) {
  .col-@{class}-push-@{index} {
    left: percentage((@index / @grid-columns));
  }
}
.calc-grid-column(@index, @class, @type) when (@type = push) and (@index = 0) {
  .col-@{class}-push-0 {
    left: auto;
  }
}
.calc-grid-column(@index, @class, @type) when (@type = pull) and (@index > 0) {
  .col-@{class}-pull-@{index} {
    right: percentage((@index / @grid-columns));
  }
}
.calc-grid-column(@index, @class, @type) when (@type = pull) and (@index = 0) {
  .col-@{class}-pull-0 {
    right: auto;
  }
}
.calc-grid-column(@index, @class, @type) when (@type = offset) {
  .col-@{class}-offset-@{index} {
    margin-left: percentage((@index / @grid-columns));
  }
}

// Basic looping in LESS
.loop-grid-columns(@index, @class, @type) when (@index >= 0) {
  .calc-grid-column(@index, @class, @type);
  // next iteration
  .loop-grid-columns((@index - 1), @class, @type);
}

// Create grid for specific class
.make-grid(@class) {
  .float-grid-columns(@class);
  .loop-grid-columns(@grid-columns, @class, width);
  .loop-grid-columns(@grid-columns, @class, pull);
  .loop-grid-columns(@grid-columns, @class, push);
  .loop-grid-columns(@grid-columns, @class, offset);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

edit the file

> grid-framework.less

and try adding this using JS

```
less.modifyVars(.col-md-2{
  '@width': 'your_value'
});
```

Or you can add the lines in the less file

```
.col-ms-2{@width: your_value}
```

Comment: how!!?? Where??

Comment: From the images you provided there is not much to go on but the file name is given and the line number provided. Now look for it and you will find it.

Comment: Fair! I'm sorry ... Let me rephrase the question with an example! How can I change the value from 16.66666667% to 19.66666667%, since the less format does this calculation automatically! ?? Since in the file, in the same line (48) there is nothing that I can change that results in this value ??

Comment: I have changed the answer. Check if it works for you.

Comment: Sorry ... yesterday I could not see your answer !! Thank you very much for your help !! But it didn´t work! I believe that this file, among others ... make the calculation so that the elements can fit in the grid .... it remains to know in which file and in what part of it I configure this information so that I have the result that I want !!